# linking with C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe failed: exit code: 1?

Tags: gcc, rust, visual-c++, tauri

I installed Rust on Windows 10 without MSVC, instead i have already `gcc` installed, i installed it using `MSYS2` and `MinGW`, i installed also `base-devel`, the `rustc` compiler is working well. I created a basic Tauri app using `create-tauri-app` npm package. When i try to build the app using `npm run tauri build` i get the following error

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\test-app>npm run tauri build

> tauri-app@0.0.0 tauri
> tauri build

     Running beforeBuildCommand `npm run build`

> tauri-app@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v4.4.9 building for production...
✓ 36 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                   0.47 kB │ gzip:  0.30 kB
dist/assets/react-35ef61ed.svg    4.13 kB │ gzip:  2.14 kB
dist/assets/index-8d1df8c2.css    1.37 kB │ gzip:  0.65 kB
dist/assets/index-000bc5e8.js   144.49 kB │ gzip: 46.58 kB
✓ built in 2.13s
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.66
   Compiling serde v1.0.188
   Compiling syn v1.0.109
   Compiling getrandom v0.1.16
error: linking with `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe` failed: exit code: 1
  |
  = note: "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe" "-fno-use-linker-plugin" "-Wl,--dynamicbase" "-Wl,--disable-auto-image-base" "-m64" "-Wl,--high-entropy-va" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsbegin.o" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rustc4UTb3V\\symbols.o" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\Desktop\\test-app\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\serde-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7\\build_script_build-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7.build_script_build.afbe961ceb65c495-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\Desktop\\test-app\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\serde-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7\\build_script_build-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7.build_script_build.afbe961ceb65c495-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\Desktop\\test-app\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\serde-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7\\build_script_build-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7.indvwvhf9jx237e.rcgu.o" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\Desktop\\test-app\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\deps" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd-274cab44dc4a644c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-0f177752b9ca8e95.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libobject-06bb167660b3da76.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libmemchr-8ab6cc09499ecf5b.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libaddr2line-126153ebe55b6775.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libgimli-3d08640ec0a90b99.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_demangle-e211ed0efcaf0dab.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libstd_detect-f17f8b04b9a04cbd.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libhashbrown-dc505c5f7a08eb2f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-29139547fec356ea.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libminiz_oxide-cab94e250dc1e17d.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libadler-e6226bb3d40532fc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libunwind-bc036f0a729eca3e.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcfg_if-b7a734954c1f5dcb.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liblibc-a254eeb9e90dc361.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\liballoc-b6fb9ac972c98305.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-6db27a6ad3c9479a.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcore-6fcad14090edadfc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-625af2eb18940f92.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lkernel32" "-ladvapi32" "-lbcrypt" "-lkernel32" "-lntdll" "-luserenv" "-lws2_32" "-lkernel32" "-lws2_32" "-lkernel32" "-lgcc_eh" "-l:libpthread.a" "-lmsvcrt" "-lmingwex" "-lmingw32" "-lgcc" "-lmsvcrt" "-luser32" "-lkernel32" "-Wl,--nxcompat" "-L" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib" "-o" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\Desktop\\test-app\\src-tauri\\target\\release\\build\\serde-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7\\build_script_build-d8c41f1ef41ee9a7.exe" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-no-pie" "-nodefaultlibs" "C:\\Users\\hayoo\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\\lib\\rsend.o"
  = note: collect2.exe: error: ld returned 53 exit status


error: could not compile `serde` (build script) due to previous error
```

C:\Users\username\.cargo\config

```
[target.x86_64-pc-windows-gnu]
linker = "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
ar = "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\ar.exe"
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use Tauri with the GNU target, because it needs the OS's native web browser. I imagine it needs to link with the Windows native libraries.